# Getting started with pion network library

Tags: c++, makefile

I have downloaded and installed the pion network library.

I am trying to build the sample web services (HelloService etc). However, I cannot find instructions on how to build the examples. Running make in the directory returns '**Nothing to be done for all**'

Has anyone ever managed to build the pion network library web service examples?

I am developing on Ubuntu 10.x

Comment: Have you tried `make clean; make`?

Comment: @larsman: I haven't managed to build yet. there is nothing to clean :)

Comment: @larsman: Thanks I managed to get it to build. I am suprised I had to run make clean first, since I had just checked out the sources from SVN...

Comment: Can someone please delete this question?. I have managed to build and test the demo apps. tx

Comment: Just write an answer and mark it as accepted. You don't have to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting tutorial here : http://prog-xp.blogspot.fr/2011/01/creating-simple-web-server-with-pion.html